# Authentication and authorization django app(backend) using keycloak

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, keycloak

I had a problem. I had a react app that authenticate, using KeyCloak. From KeyCloak-server i recieve some credentials, like tokens, uuid of user and etc. Then, i am trying to access api on Django Backend, but request.user is Anonymous User. So, how can I can authenticate Django DRF? Should I send credentials from frontend to backend and create User model on backend or I don't need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup some authentication, for example using JWT. https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/django/jwt/